# Is there a default limit to the amount of memory a process may use?

Tags: server, 10.04, ram

Running 64-bit Matlab 7.12 on a 64-bit 10.04 Ubuntu Server. When I try run a big problem that should need 46GB of memory (the server has 72GB of Memory and plenty of swap space), the experimental script is killed by the OS (See dmesg below).

```
dmesg returns after the job is killed:
[26687918.130102] Out of memory: kill process 2630 (bash) score 4999042 or a child
[26687918.130103] Killed process 2774 (MATLAB)
```

> So my question is: is there a default per process memory limit in Ubuntu Server 10.04, and if so, can it be modified?

Thanks,
Gordon

Comment: Have a look at [How can I allocate more memory to a process](http://superuser.com/questions/525866/how-can-i-increase-the-memory-allocated-to-a-process-in-ubuntu-server)

Comment: what does `ulimit -a` show? Also take a look at [Taming the OOM killer](http://lwn.net/Articles/318269/)

Comment: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-core-dumps.html

Comment: @ortang:
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
scheduling priority             (-e) 20
pending signals                 (-i) 16382
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192 (all the other fields are unlimited)

Comment: As per the post suggested by @Mitch, this seems to be a Matlab-specific issue (a simple C program can allocate 46GB+ quite happily). The exact version is 7.12.0.635 (R2011a) and it is the 64-bit Linux version. According to Mathworks, this version should be about to support arrays of many TBs.

Comment: @Gordonei can you use the [memory function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/memory.html) and confirm this?

Comment: Could it be that even a self-written Java app is bound to some limit? I face a problem with a ~10GB file on a legacy setup on Ubuntu 12. The app it just hanging during the download, thereby stopping other jobs, and crashing when another job runs on top of it, or could it be a limit of the file/download/time that is not set by the server's defaults, but by the app? This might even have crashed the server, it had to be hard reset after wild BIOS-like errors in the console tracing to very system like errors.